# STM32 USART RX with DMA

Tags: stm32, embedded, uart, dma

I'm trying to set up UART communication with DMA using the STM32F103C8 controller. I'm trying to receive data with DMA, but I can't receive data continuously. Can anyone correct me if I made a mistake? I'm using STM32f103C8 registers to code.

Communication: USART3
Pins: PB10-TX, PB11-RX
DMA channels: DMA1_channel1 for TX, DMA1_channel3 for RX

```
#include<stm32f10x.h>
uint8_t rx_data[20];
    
void USART3_config(void)
{
  RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_USART3EN;
  RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_DMA1EN;
            
  USART3->BRR = 0x0EA6; // for 9600 baurd rate
  USART3->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TE | USART_CR1_RXNEIE | USART_CR1_RE;
  USART3->CR3 |= USART_CR3_DMAT | USART_CR3_DMAR;
  USART3->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;

  NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART3_IRQn);
}
    
void USART_DMA_RX_init(void)
{
  RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_DMA1EN;

  DMA1_Channel3->CPAR = (uint32_t)&USART3->DR;
  DMA1_Channel3->CMAR = (uint32_t)rx_data;
  DMA1_Channel3->CNDTR = 20;
  DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= DMA_CCR3_MINC | DMA_CCR3_TCIE | DMA_CCR3_HTIE;
  DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= DMA_CCR3_EN;

  NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn);
}

int main(void)
{
  RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPBEN | RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN;
  GPIOB->CRH = 0x00008B00;
  USART_DMA_RX_init();
  USART3_config();
      
  while(1)
  {}
}
    
void DMA1_Channel3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  if ((DMA1->ISR & DMA_ISR_HTIF3) == DMA_ISR_HTIF3)
  {
    DMA1->IFCR = DMA_IFCR_CHTIF3;
  }
  else if ((DMA1->ISR & DMA_ISR_TCIF3) == DMA_ISR_TCIF3)
  {
    DMA1->IFCR = DMA_IFCR_CGIF3 | DMA_IFCR_CTCIF3;
  }
}

void USART3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  if ((USART3->SR & USART_SR_RXNE) == USART_SR_RXNE)
  {
    USART3->SR &= ~ USART_SR_RXNE;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I can't receive data continuously"? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Thank you for your response. i can able to receive data only once and can't receive the data after that

Comment: That's how you have configured it. CNDTR is set to 20. After 20 bytes, DMA is complete and stops. It must be restarted to process further data. And since DMA is used, the USART IRQ isn't needed.

Comment: sorry, I couldn't get you can you brief me so that I can understand clearly?

Comment: The code configures DMA to process 20 bytes. It does not configure DMA to run continuously. You have two options: Either restart DMA after the DMA interrupt (with TCIF3 bit set) has occurred, or configure DMA for circular mode.

Comment: I tried once with circular mode I can able to receive the data but the index position is changing                                                                                                                                               "restart DMA after the DMA interrupt (with TCIF3 bit set) has occurred" i tried to disable and enable the DMA after the DMA interrupt but it didn't work

Comment: Please add the code that didn't work to your question. Then we can have a look at it.

Comment: Also you should always declare DMA buffers `volatile`, or the compiler might decide to generate nonsense during optimization.

Comment: @Lundin Actually, you shouldn't unless there's code that reads (polls) the same bytes of the buffer in a loop which is, of course, nonsensical itself. So please don't confuse others over your unfounded fears of "compilers generating nonsense during optimization".

Comment: @Surendran If you use DMA for RX, don't enable the RX interrupt. Note that your code enables USART_CR1_RXNEIE and DMAR at the same time. As others already noted, you need to enable DMA circular mode in order to receive data continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of pointers:

1. There's no need for this callback as it's not needed void USART3_IRQHandler(void)
2. You've set only 20 bytes to be transferred. So
   it'll stop after 20 bytes. When it comes to DMA reception, you need to specify
   the length of the incoming bytes.
3. Also as @Lundin said, declare buffer to be volatile

Comment: EmbeddedAlpha - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as the site rules differ from typical forums. (b) We do not allow links unless they have a *very specific reason* why they are useful for this answer. Therefore your GitHub link has been removed. You can [edit your site profile and add it there](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/edit/364734), if you want people to know about it. (c) Don't ask questions in an *answer*. If you need to ask clarification questions to an OP, that should be done in a *comment* when you have [50 points](/help/privileges/comment).